# Why autocomplete of jqueryUI don't display result?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui, autocomplete

I try to use jqueryUI   autocomplete in mvc project .I look at the console and found that when write characters in input of autocomplete I get all data but this data don't display in blow of input .How to fix this?

```
    $('#Departure').autocomplete({
     source: '@Url.Action("GetCityAndAirport", "Flight", "CityAndAirports")'
 });
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#option-source the response returned from the server can be:

- An array of strings: `[ "Choice1", "Choice2" ]`
- An array of objects with label and value properties: `[ { label: "Choice1", value: "value1" }, ... ]`

But it looks like the server is wrapping the array in an object.

If the server can return: `["Value 1", "Value 2"]` instead of `{"obj": ["Value 1", "Value 2"]}` you should see the results.

**Edit:**
Another option is to use the `function` form of the source option and process the response:

```
$('.selector').autocomplete({
    source: function( request, response )  {
        $.getJSON('url', { term: request.term }, function( data ) {
           response( data.obj );
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

That's besouse you should pass an array to autocomplate `source` according to [documentation](https://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#option-source) or set function. You either can change your data on server side or select only array on client side.

It's easier and cleaner to change server side in your case. response should be like this:

```
[ "Choice1", "Choice2" ]
```

**not:**

```
{ obj: [ "Choice1", "Choice2" ]}
```